# How to have a figure with caption in multicol environment?

Tags: floats, multicol

I am having the following problem with adding a figure inside the `multicol` environment:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

 \begin{multicols}{2}
 a test file for picture inclusion along with the captions and labeling
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=5cma]{Cauchy_sequence_illustration-png}\\
 \caption{Lets see}\label{pinki}
\end{figure}
\end{multicols}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{Cauchy_sequence_illustration-png}\\
 \caption{Lets see}\label{pinki}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

After this while I am pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> (usually I compile like this in DVI format and then clicking "dvi--->pdf" I convert it into PDF document.) the picture in `multicol` environment is not shown in YAP Viewer but the second one (which is outside of `multicol` environment) is shown along with the caption.

Kindly help me how to handle this problem. Please note that I am using the figure in `.ps` format. And I am not allowed to use any other format according to the instruction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`multicol` package doesn't work well with `figure` environment (which is a float). You stand better chances by using the `\includegraphics` and add the caption using `\captionof` macro from `caption` (or `\capt-of`) package.

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}   %%% remove demo in your file
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

 \begin{multicols}{2}
 a test file for picture inclusion along with the captions and labeling
{ \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{Cauchy_sequence_illustration-png}\\
 \captionof{figure}{Lets see}\label{pinki}
}
\end{multicols}

\begin{figure}[htb]
 \centering
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{Cauchy_sequence_illustration-png}\\
 \caption{Lets see}\label{pinki}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: WOW!! That really worked. Thank you so much sir.

Comment: Dear Sir, Two more doubts I have. Will you please help me ? 1) How to put entire figure in a box? 2)How to adjust two figures side by side , not by up-down ?

Comment: @AnjanDebnath For box, use `\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{Cauchy_sequence_illustration-png}}` and for putting them side by side, you may put the second figure inside the `multicols` environment. It will be better, if you post a new question with more details on your requirements.

Comment: Sir, I have post my situation here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198892/how-to-adjust-two-pictures-side-by-side-in-multicol-environment