# How to adjust two pictures side by side in just one column of multicol environment?

Tags: floats, multicol

First of all, thanks to the group member Harish Kumar because of whose advise finally I was able to fix the caption line under the figure/ float in multicol environment. This is what I then faced:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}   %%% remove demo in your file
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

 \begin{multicols}{2}
 a test file for picture inclusion along with the captions and labeling
\begin{center}
 \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Cauchy_sequence_illustration-png}}
 \captionof{figure}{Cauchy Seq1}\label{Cauchy1}
 \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Cauchy_sequence_illustration-png}}
 \captionof{figure}{Cauchy Seq2}\label{Cauchy2}
 \end{center}
 \end{multicols}

 \end{document}
```

The problem is : I am willing to include two pictures "side by side" rather than up-down way. But in vain. Can anyone please help me how to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want two column only for some portion or full? You can put the figures outside `multicols` environment. Is that an option?

Comment: @Harish Kumar   No sir. Within the multicol environment I need it. Not outside the multicol environment, the two pictures should be placed. But if we wish we can ignore "\fbox{}" matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it like this?

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}   %%% remove demo in your file
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

 \begin{multicols}{2}
 a test file for picture inclusion along with the captions and labeling

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.5\columnwidth}
\centering
 \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax]{Cauchy_sequence_illustration-png}}
 \captionof{figure}{\protect\raggedright Cauchy Seq1}\label{Cauchy1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\columnwidth}
\centering
 \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax]{Cauchy_sequence_illustration-png}}
 \captionof{figure}{\protect\raggedright Cauchy Seq2}\label{Cauchy2}
 \end{minipage}
 \kant[2]
 \end{multicols}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your effort sir, but this is not what I want although still this was helpful information to me. 

What i am seeking is to include these two pictures in "just one of the two columns" (for example left column) in the multicol environment. How shall I do it sir?

Comment: @AnjanDebnath Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Finally I have got my desired pictures. But sir, in my machine while I am pressing ctrl+shift+x, compilation is being interrupted by saying that "Latex error: File `kantlipsum.sty' not found".

What to do now Sir? The process is not working although this is exactly what I was searching for past few months.

Comment: What to do sir this time?

Comment: @AnjanDebnath: `kantlipsum` is just for dummy text. Remove `\usepackage{kantlipsum}` and `\kant[2]`. Fill in your text and compile.

Comment: I am grateful to you sir. Past several months I tried to figure out but in vain and finally today because of you I ultimately got the answer. Thank you Thank you so much for your beautiful solution.

Comment: @AnjanDebnath You are welcome. BTW no need of *sir* :-)